# How to see keepalived priority number when it changed

Tags: keepalived

I have used keepalived to archive high availability for nginx. I set initial priority 101 for MASTER, 100 for BACKUP and I can see `/var/log/messages` :

```
Keepalived_vrrp[34483]: VRRP_Script(chk_nginx) failed
Keepalived_vrrp[34483]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Received higher prio advert
Keepalived_vrrp[34483]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) Entering BACKUP STATE
Keepalived_vrrp[34483]: VRRP_Instance(VI_1) removing protocol VIPs
```

Is there any way to see the changed priority number to look into why my machine change role state?

```
vrrp_script chk_nginx {
   script "killall -0 nginx"
   interval 1
   weight -2
   fall 2
   rise 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tcpdump to see the advertisements on the wire.  This will show you the source machine sending the advertisement that's higher.

```
tcpdump -vvv -n -i eth0 host 224.0.0.18
```

Comment: No other way to write detail log  to `/var/log/messages`?

Comment: You can add a '-D' daemon option in your startup script.

Comment: `tcpdump -vvv -n -i eth0 dst 224.0.0.18 and src 172.29.88.224` shows me the priority. Thanks!